# How do I install reddit on a local OS X machine?

Tags: python, web-applications, pylons, osx-mountain-lion, reddit

They have provided a install script for Ubutu. But how do I install reddit on a Mac OS X machine ? [Mountain Lion]

The dependencies are listed here : https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/Dependencies

How do I install these ? Just google for these, get the .dmg & install ?

next, this installation guide works on OS X also ? Link - https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/Install-guide 
If not what all changes I have to make?

I am a beginner & I would really appreciate any help regarding this. Thank you !

Comment: YOu are a beginner and try to install a huge pill of third-party components...sorry, wrong person for the job....learn to ride a bike before trying to fly to the moon

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would really appreciate if you tell me the correct way...

Comment: how did your install go avi?

I've got it installed on VirtualBox but am trying to get the Python code to connect over the network interface so I can run PyCharm on the Mac and have it talk to the servers running on Ubuntu whether on my machine or over the network.

Seems possible but it is a real pain to get so many parts working compatibly without version conflicts and such. The Ubuntu script is so easy by contrast. But I like an IDE for development. Ah well...

Answer (score 4):

Don't try to run on OSX natively. There is no point. Simply do the following:

1. Install [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) for OS X.
2. Create an appropriate Ubuntu 12.04 virtual machine.
3. Run the install script.

Even if you are running Ubuntu 12.04 I would still recommend this approach so you can cleanly separate the environment you need for day-to-day use, from the reddit environment that you may only require from time to time.

Comment: Thank you ! I guess I better go with this method.